# Array loop class for adding strings into array not working

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I have an array which has x indexes according to what the user inputs (NoOfArrays). A method called add is used to add a string to the next null index in the array.. but none of this works..

so when an array of x indexes are created, i should be able to add a string into the array, remove it, check if the array is full, check if a "user input" string is already in the array, etc

```
public class Bag1
{
    private String[] store;

    public Bag1(int NoOfArrays)
    {
        store = new String[NoOfArrays];
        for (int i=0;i>store.length;i++){
            store[i] = null;
        }
    }
    public boolean isFull(){
        boolean isTrue = true;
        for (int i=0;i>store.length;i++) {
            if (store[i] == null){
                isTrue = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isTrue;
    }

    public void add(String s){
        for (int i=0;i>store.length;i++){
            if (store[i] == null){
                store[i] = s;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(String s){
        boolean isTRUE = false;
        for (int i=0;i>store.length;i++){
            if (store[i] == s){
                isTRUE = true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Does not have " + s);
            }
        }        
        return isTRUE;
    }

    public void remove(String s){
        for (int i=0;i>store.length;i++)
            if (store[i] ==s){
                store[i] = null;
                break;
            }
    }

    public void showStrings(){
        for (int i=0;i>store.length;i++){
            System.out.print(store[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (store[i] == s){` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is incorrect

```
for (int i=0;i>store.length;i++){
```

Since `i=0`, the condition `i>store.length` will evaluate to false, and loop will not be entered

Change it to

```
 for (int i=0;i<store.length;i++){
```

Also, as @Pshemo commented, use [`equals()` to compare string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

There are several critical problems in your code. Main of them is that you use invalid method of `String`'s compare: `store[i] ==s`. It should be `s.equals(store[i])`.

Another one is incorrect loops condition structure. As mentioned @sam you should change it from `i>store.length` to `i<store.length`.